# How do I pass a bearer token in wso2 Publisher?

Tags: wso2

i using wso2 to manager my group's api,so i publish my api to wso2 Publisher.
  My api has its own authentication by send a bearer token.The swagger document have the authorize button ,but when i import my api definition in wso2 Publisher.the authorize button is disappear.
i have these question
[image]

1、How should I send the original beaer token?
2、when i use swagger3 definition,it show some error,swaager3 is not supported by the import function?

anyone has suggesstion?

my wso2 version is: WSO2 API-M v4.1.0

Comment: Provide the errors you are getting for the question 2

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager does support Swagger2 and Open API Specification (OAS) 3 and above.

And with regard to Bearer tokens in API Manager, you can generate a bearer token using the DevPortal for your APIs. You need to create a new Applicaiton, and subscribe to your API, and then you can generate a new JWT-based bearer token.

Please check this section in detail - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/consume-api-overview/

Comment: hi joy,My api itself requires certification. How do I add this certification. above you say,it seem is wso2 itself bearer token ,but i need add my own bearer token

Comment: Did you check this - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/securing-apis-using-certificate-bound-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is OAUth protected you can use Endpoint security to add OAuth configs to generate a backend bearer token when calling the API. Take a look at [this document.](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/endpoints/endpoint-security/oauth-2.0/). Also if you want to import backend certificates to API Manager take a look at [this document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/endpoints/certificates/#adding-a-certificate-for-an-endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

If your expectation is to send the Authorization header to the backend, you can add the following configs to the deployment.toml and restart the API Manager.

```
[apim.oauth_config]
enable_outbound_auth_header = false
```

Also If you don't need any token validation from the API Manager, you can disable the security for the API[1].

Regarding your second concern,  that error can be due to some issue with the swagger file. Make sure your swagger file followed the correct standard by putting that into the swagger editor[2].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/disable-security/

[2] https://editor.swagger.io/

Answer (score 0):

When you expose an API with WSO2 API Manager, you have the option to add an additional security layer for your API. You can find more information on this via this [article](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2018/07/securing-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/).

If your API itself has security, still you can front the API with a different/separate layer of security as above and if the request is valid, API Manager itself can generate the backend token and invoke the API. This is called endpoint security configurations and API Manager supports OAuth2-protected backends with `client credential` and `password` grant types. You can refer [this doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/endpoints/endpoint-security/oauth-2.0/) for such endpoint security configurations.

If you don't want to secure the API from API Manager layer and only needs to use the backend security by passing the backend bear token with the request, then you need to disable security for the API. By default security is enabled for the API when exposed via the API Manager. You can disable security at each operation level by using as per this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/disable-security/).

When security is enabled from API Manager, it validates the "Authorization" named header sent with the request. If you want to use this name for the backend authorization header and needs to use a different name for the API Manager's authorization header, you can change it as per this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-oauth2-tokens/#customizing-the-authorization-header).